# What about the Kinect SDK requires VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, kinect

The Kinect SDK says that it requires Visual Studio 2010.  What about it makes 2008 not sufficient?  Is it ABI issues?

Comment: What does the requirements document say?

Answer (score 1):

The Kinect for Windows SDK is built on top of .NET 4.0.  Since VS2008 does not support .NET 4.0, you have to use VS2010.  Any version of 2010 should work.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  Do you know if that means that you have to use C# or C++/CLI instead of standard C++?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the official Microsoft SDK, you'll need to use Visual C# or Visual C++.

Comment: I mean does it require managed C++ (which is now called C++/CLI afaik for .Net), or is the C++ SDK standard unmanaged C++?

Comment: You can use unmanaged C++.  Here's some C++ sample code using the Beta version of the SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855386.aspx